# In Appium, is it possible to check that an app's dark mode feature is enabled?

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios, python-appium

In the app, I am able to go to Settings and turn on the Dark Mode feature. 
I want to check that this feature is working and write a test validating that the app went into Dark Mode successfully.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the particular attribute (text or background color, etc) of an element that changes, you can use the [Get Element Attribute](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/attribute/) command

```
MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("SomeAccessibilityID");
String tagName = element.getAttribute("content-desc");
```